# Swap two columns depending on condition for third column in linux

Tags: linux, multiple-columns

I have a file with 3 columns like this

```
  Col1         Col2          Col3 
   A            B             <-
   C            D             ->
   E            F             ->
```

I want to swap the entries of the Col1 and Col2 whenever there is

```
<-
```

in the third column. I want my output file to be like

```
 Col1         Col2          Col3 
   B            A             ->
   C            D             ->
   E            F             ->
```

Comment: how about `awk`?

Comment: how to use awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '($3=="<-"){$3=$2;$2=$1;$1=$3;$3="->"}1' <file>
```

Essentially, if `$3=="<-"`, then swap the columns and redefine `$3`. Then print.

Answer (score 0):

An short awk example is

```
 cat foooo | awk '{if (match($3,"<-")){print $2,$1,$3}else{print $1,$2,$3}}'
```

where foooo is the file name.

If you also want to change the "<-" then the code would be

```
 cat foooo | awk '{if (match($3,"<-")){print $2,$1,"->"}else{print $1,$2,$3}}'
```

Comment: removed UUOC but the `$3` need to be changed too.